# Regex match certain IDs

Tags: java, regex

I need help with some tricky regex to solve (for me!) and hope I can learn something to write some myself in the future.

I need to match all of the following IDs:

```
#1
#12
#123
#1234
#5069
#316&
#316.
#316;
```

and do not want to match leading zeros and numbers that end with `]` or `[` or are between `()`.

```
#0155
#0000155
#1123]
#1123[
(#1125)
```

I have come up with something like this: `(#[1-9]\d{0,})`, but it matches all of the above. So, I tried a different stuff like:

```
"(#[1-9]\\d{0,})([\\s,<\\.:&;\\)])"
"(#[1-9]+)([\\s,<\\.])"
"(?m)(#[1-9]+)(.,\(,\))"
```

But what I really want to do is `(#[1-9]\d{0,})` to match all numbers *BUT NOT FOLLOWING `[` OR `]` OR `(` OR `)`*.

How can I express something like this in a regex?

P.S.: The Regex needs to be used in Java.

Maybe someone can help to solve this, even better if he can explain how he got the way to the solution, so i can learn something new and help others when they struggle with the same problem.

kind regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use possesive quantifier.

```
"#[1-9]\\d*+(?![\\[\\])])"
```

`\\d*+` matches all zero or more character greedily and the `+` eixts after `*` won't let the regex engine to backtrack.

Add an optional `\\W`, if you want to match also the following non-word character.

```
"#[1-9]\\d*+(?![\\[\\])])\\W?"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mP2cF6/1)

Comment: Thats what I wanted! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following solution:

```
#[1-9]\d*(?![\[\])])\b[&.;]?
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cT4rF2/1)

**REGEX**:

- `#` - Matches `#` literally
- `[1-9]` - 1 digit from 1 to 9
- `\d*` - 0 or more digits
- `(?![\[\])])` - A negative lookahead making sure there is no `[`, `]` or `)` after the digits
- `\b` - A word boundary
- `[&.;]?` - An optional (`?`) character group matching `&`, `.` or `;` literally.

Sample code:

```
String str = "#1\n#12\n#123\n#1234\n#5069\n#316&\n#316.\n#316;\nand not matches (leading zeros) and numbers that end with ] or [ or are between ().\n\n#0155\n#0000155\n#1123]\n#1123[\n(#1125)";
String rx = "#[1-9]\\d*(?![\\[\\])])\\b[&.;]?";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(rx);
Matcher m = ptrn.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/vhpq2k)

**UPDATE**

You can achieve the expected results with atomic grouping that prevents the regex engine from backtracking into it.

```
String rx = "#(?>[1-9]\\d*)(?![\\[\\])])[^\\w&&[^\n]]?";
```

In plain words, the check for brackets will be performed only after the last digit matched. See [updated demo](http://ideone.com/Re6YIN).

The `[^\\w&&[^\n]]?` pattern optionally matches any non-alphanumeric character but a newline. The newline is excluded from the character class using a character class intersection technique.

Comment: Even though its almost right and because you explained it very detailed. I vote this one up :)!

Comment: Perhaps it does not work in all contexts, so possessive behavior is really better. The check for brackets will be only made after all digits are matched, not just after each digit. But there is another way to do the same: atomic group. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to test this in Java at the moment, but how about

`"^#[1-9][0-9]*[&.;]?$"`

(Any string starting with a '#', then a character from 1-9, then zero or more characters from 0-9, then a '&', '.' or ';' or nothing, end string)

EDIT: This only works if every id to check is in its own string, otherwise you'd need one of examples from other answers.